# Upgrading Opensource chef to Enterprise chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have installed opensource chef 12 in my environment. I want to upgrade that to enterprise chef(premium). can some one tell me how can we move to enterprise chef12(premium).

Answer (score 0):

Premium features are added via plugin. Check out the original product announcement:

https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/11/25/chef-server-12-released/

Comment: Yes.We can install premium features with plugin but that is valid for 25 nodes. What if we want to extend the premium features permanent one. I mean enterprise agreement.

Comment: @SASI Don't know to be honest. At work we already have an Enterprise agreement. Why don't you contact chef? I'm sure they'd be delighted to talk to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer, but opscode recently has started a https://discourse.chef.io - pretty responsive chef mail list, I am pretty sure you will get the answer here. At least I succeeded here in my many questions.